# How to access PHP custom header via mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to access PHP custom header value through *`mod_rewrite`* condition. My attempted something like this:

```
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
  'proxy' => $proxy,
  'request_fulluri' => True,
  'header' => "MY_CUSTOM_HEADER: foo\n\r"
 )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$content = file_get_contents("http://$url", false, $context);
```

Using mod_rewrite condition as shown:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:MY_CUSTOM_HEADER} ^foo$
```

Comment: Nitpick: headers should not use underscores, and custom headers should be prefixed with `X-`, eg: `X-My-Custom-Header: foo`